# Deploy ASP.NET website to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 website and I want to deploy it to SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2012. How to do this? Can someone please explain this process in detail if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose creating and deploying on-premises provider-hosted app for SharePoint. In this you can use can deploy a provider hosted app to redirect users to your site. For details check :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bspann/archive/2013/01/19/asp-net-mvc-based-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-on-premises.aspx

Another option would be you can convert you asp.net site package to Sharepoint deployment package. You can follow the step from here :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21465/Converting-an-ASP-NET-site-into-a-SharePoint-site

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/031248aa-7b13-40a5-8369-f4267bbc28c6/how-to-deploy-the-aspnet-web-application-in-the-sharepoint-service?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

All is same as local IIS deployment.

Just need to modify `web.config` by adding some settings in `appsettings` section as follows:

1. add key="isDeploy" value="true"/>
2. add key="FTPServer" value="ipAddressOfServer"/>
3. add key="PortNumber" value="portnumber"/>
4. add key="FTPUserName" value="yourremotemachinename"/>
5. add key="FTPPassword" value="yourpasswordofremoteconnection"/>